# SQL table column filling

Tags: sql

i have a table A as

```
ID  EFF_DT
1   2/12/2013
2   4/12/2013
3   6/3/2013
4   5/15/2013
```

I need a temp table #temp as

```
ID  EFF_DT       END_DATE
1   2/12/2013    4/11/2013
2   4/12/2013    5/14/2013
3   5/15/2013    6/2/2013
4   6/3/2013     cURRDATE
```

What is the best way to achieve this? END_DATE for an EFF_DT is 1 day less than next EFF_DT in order of sorting

Comment: can someone adjust the column format pls

Comment: sorry ignore the ID column ..it is not important

Comment: What code have you tried and what were your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a correlated subquery (in any query engine):

```
select a.*,
       coalesce((select min(efe_dt) + 1
                 from a a2
                 where a2.efe_dt > a.efe_dt
                ), CURRENT_DATE) as end_date
from a;
```

Some caveats, based on the dialect of SQL.  The code for subtracting a day can take various formats (such as using a `dateadd()` function).  The constant/function for the current date time also varies among dialects.

Some SQL engines support the ANSI standard `lag()`/`lead()` functions.  This makes the code easier.  The following is how you can do this in SQL Server 2012:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(efe_dt) over (order by efe_dt)),
                cast(get_date() as date)
               ) as end_date
from a;
```

Comment: Very nice! I've never seen lead before. However, it misses the last day in the series - it must be doing a self inner join under the covers?

Comment: Just to make it clear, it's only your second one which misses the last row. Your first one is fine, and is far faster than mine.

Comment: @simonatrcl . . . What do you mean "misses the last row"?  The second query is selecting all rows from `a`, so no rows should be missing.

Comment: @Gordon - you're right, it does include it. However it doesn't give getdate() for the missing date. I repeats the eff_date. (I was trying it on a table I have which is broader than the result window, and saw the last date on the end_date column so assumed....)

Answer (score 0):

Freehand SQL:

```
select a1.I2, a1.eff_date, case when a2.eff_date is null then getdate()
                                else DateAdd(D, -1, a2.eff_date) end End_date
from A a1
left outer join A a2 on a2.eff_date > a1.eff_date
where a2.eff_date is null
or a2.eff_date = (select min(a3.eff_date) from A a3 where a3.eff_date > a1.eff_date)
```

Looks like it works.